# Where was Hotel Scene Shot in "On My Way?"

Tags: film-location

In the 2013 French film with Catherine Deneuve,  there's a part of the film set in a beautiful hotel situated on a lake. Catherine Deneuve's character goes there with her grandson and meets up with the other contestants from the 1968 Ms. France competition.  The hotel and its setting look beautiful.  I wondered where the location is?

Comment: Why a downvote?  There is a tag film-location for exactly this type of question.  There are many similar questions that nobody seems to object to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?locations=Hotel%20Palace%20de%20Menthon,%20Menthon-Saint-Bernard,%20Haute-Savoie,%20France&ref_=ttloc_loc_1) it seems that the location is

Hotel Palace de Menthon, Menthon-Saint-Bernard, Haute-Savoie, France

[image]